# MySql - Join and count data in record

Tags: mysql

I try to count data records by user id but result is total rows record and I have data below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1HCN.png)

I use query here:

```html
SELECT user.id, COUNT(upload.user_id), upload.file_name FROM upload Right JOIN user ON upload.user_id = user.id;
```

Comment: This might help https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count by `user_id` then you don't need to `JOIN` at all, it can be a simple `GROUP BY` with `COUNT`, e.g.:

```
SELECT user_id, COUNT(*)
FROM upload
GROUP BY user_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way `SELECT us.id, (select count(*) from upload where user_id=us.id), u.file_name FROM upload u, user us where u.user_id = us.id;`